# Error executing code: Wrong argument type for function

Tags: c#, axapta, ax

I have some code in c# which uses the AX Business connector, and its like this:

```
AxaptaRecord OrderRecord = (AxaptaRecord)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("BTNOnlineOrder", "getSalesOrder", salesRef);

if (OrderRecord.Found)
{
     AxaptaObject Lines = (AxaptaObject)OrderRecord.Call("querySalesLine");
     AxaptaObject qrLines = (AxaptaObject)ax.CreateAxaptaObject("QueryRun", Lines);

     while ((bool)qrLines.Call("next"))
     {
          int tableid = (int)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("Global", "tableName2Id", "InventTable");
          AxaptaRecord r = (AxaptaRecord)qrLines.Call("get", tableid);
     }  
}
```

I get the following error when I try to call the "get" method:

> Error executing code: Wrong argument type for function.

tableid returns an int value, 175, so it's not due to tableid being null or something.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The query that is returned by querySalesLine - is it a custom query or the default SalesLine query provided with Ax? I just wanted to make sure the query has a datasource in it pointing to InventTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by using the `getNo` method and passing 1 as the parameter. I'm not sure if it's the correct way or not but it worked for me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa612609(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: Ok, so I assume you only needed the SalesLine datasource. Using getNo will do that, the only risk is that some other Ax solution might change the datasource order, and you might get the wrong datasource. If you replace "InventTable" with "SalesLine" in your original code you will get the same functionality. Of course, this approach depends on the datasource name, but generally you can count on the name staying the same more than the datasource order.

Comment: You're right, that worked, so is using my original way the best way of doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is "it depends". Both approaches can break. It is a matter of estimating which approach has least chances of breaking - and I do not have hard data to support one over the other. Here is another thread with some opinions: https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/p/66715/121651.aspx

Comment: Yeah I think the name of the datasource is likely to stay the same

Comment: I have to correct myself: if you noticed the first parameter to 
"get" method is tableId, so that's not the data source name, but the first table of this type from the query. But I also think it is less likely you will add duplicate tables to a query.

Answer (score 2):

If the query that you use does not have a datasource pointing to InventTable you will get this (confusing) error. I've verified this code throws this exception on the default SalesLine query in the Ax sys layer. I agree, it is a confusing error.

If you need InventTable in your consuming code you will need to define a custom query and return that from querySalesLine method.